# Binomial Coefficient is odd condition in binary system

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Here's a question that I encountered in Niven Zuckerman's Introduction to Theory of Numbers book (Problem 16,2.2)
[The question from the book part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOFJ3.jpg)

[Part 2 of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQODD.jpg)

I showed the part where all coefficients of the polynomial are even. But I was stuck when I tried the ${n}\choose{k}$ is odd part. I tried by expanding n and k in binary and then computing the binomial coefficient but it is a dead end. I also couldn't understand and solve the binary weight part. Any ideas or suggestions will be very helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) and [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem)?

Comment: No, I haven't studied yet. This question is actually from solutions of congruences

Comment: Does that mean you'd prefer a solution that doesn't use those theorems?

Comment: I read Lucas Theorem just now and it seems understandable, but it would be preferable for me if the solution doesn't use Kummer's Theorem.